# DropDownListFor doesn't bind to value when moved inside EditorFor template

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to move the likes of this into an editor template:

```
<div class="field">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CountryId)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CountryId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x, Model.CountryOptions, "Please select")
</div>
```

Where `Model.CountryOptions` is a prefilled `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, and everything works perfectly while in the main template.

So, I replace the above with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.CountryId, "DropDownList", new { options = Model.CountryOptions, optionLabel = "Please select" })
```

and inside EditorTemplates/DropDownList.cshtml I have:

```
<div class="field">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["options"], (string)ViewData["optionLabel"])
</div>
```

This all appears the same as before and binds to the model correctly on posting, but now any existing value is not being marked as selected in the drop down list on initial load.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a bug or simply by design, but when calling *DropDownList* from the editor template, the only way to set the initial selected item is by setting the *Selected* property on one of the *SelectListItem*s.

My suggested fix is, when you set `Model.CountryOptions` make sure the default option is selected.

Comment: But It does manage to set it correctly even inside an editor template if binding to a sub property of the template's model type, e.g. `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address)` with EditorTemplates/Address.cshtml containing `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryId)`.

Comment: @stovroz The difference is that, in the editor template, the current name is an empty string (when you do `DropDownListFor(x => x)` or `DropDownList("")`). That's the case when it doesn't work, but it does for sub-properties. See the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly set the selected object when passing in the SelectList something like the one below. If your CountryOption is a list this should work.

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.CountryId, "DropDownList", new { options = new SelectList(Model.CountryOptions, Model.CountryID), optionLabel = "Please select" })
```